# Inside of the cookies turn up soft, almost uncooked?

Tags: baking, temperature, cookies

I don't know what temperatures I have to be using to bake cookies but I am following a European cookie recipe:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LON4tuXR93A

The problem is I searched for the same recipe and found out many different ones with almost the same ingredients but their baking instructions vary wildly from cooking for 35 mins at 150C to cooking for 15 mins at 200C.

I am not sure what temp I have to use so I used 380F for 25 mins (+5 min preheat) that barely made the outer layer firm enough. It's not very hard but definitely formed a cookie shell which would be enough.

The problem is the inside of the cookies are very soft, almost like pre-baking.

Lastly I use baking paper and put the cookies on top of the pizza stone as I thought it wouldn't hurt to leave it. I read that it helps regulate heat throughout the oven.

In any case this is the ingredients:

- 350g sugar
- 150g almond flour
- 7 egg whites
- almond extract

Comment: I can't open the video link at work, but what kind of cookie is this supposed to be? If it is in the macaron family, then the insides are supposed to stay soft and gooey.

Comment: Once upon a time I tried to make a cake. I followed the recipe to a T. I got soup. I tried agin, double checking everything - I got soup. It was tasty chocolate soup, but it was soup. At this juncture a relative who happened to have taught domestic science for some decades in the UK dropped in. And I Quoth: "Cook it until it's done - the recipe is clearly wrong." We got cake...

Comment: Hey guys, they are supposed to look like this: http://www.yemek-tarifleri.cc/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/acibadem-kurabiyesi.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the pizza stone for cookies.

Stones **absorb** a ton of your oven's heat and will really mess up your baking times. They're designed to be preheated in your oven before you ever put a pizza (or other item) on them. I have never tried it before but you might be able to use the pizza stone if you preheated it but then you have to put your cookies on a hot surface which may cause them to misbehave in other ways.

Cookies should be baked on light-toned heavy-duty metal baking sheets (or as close as you can get to that) because the metal **transfers** the heat, it doesn't **absorb** it.

That's how you get well-baked cookies.

Comment: Thanks I will try it next time. If I don't have metal baking sheet, putting the baking paper directly on the oven rack wouldn't work?

Comment: Not really. You need something under them. You can get pairs of low quality but perfectly serviceable baking sheets at your grocery store or at a kitchen store like bed bath and beyond for $10-12 or singles for less. Or check out your closest reuse shop like Goodwill. It's well worth it if you plan to make cookies often.